# rewrite url in .htaccess

Tags: seo

I have url rewrite problem.

my file is present in

www.example.com/test2/test.php

i want to write url as

www.example.com/test.html

my code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On<br />
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ test2.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ test2.php?id=$1
rewriterule ^([a-za-z0-9-/]+).html$ test2.php?id=$1
rewriterule ^([a-za-z0-9-/]+).html/$ test2.php?id=$1
```

.htaccess file is in test2 directory.

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ test2.php?id=$1 [L]
```